# Get date previous April 1st from a date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I need to run a MySQL query and get a date from the database which I know how to do, but I need to do an operation which requires me to get the previous 1st April in the same query.

For example:

```
SELECT `Date`,(getpreviousAprilDate as month) FROM `sometable`
```

To clarify this further: I need to get a date from the database in the date column. It could be any date eg 2016-02-15 or 2015-01-12 and from this I need to put in another column the previous April date. So if the date was 2015-01-12 the previous April would be 2014-04-01.

Comment: Cannot understand Your question. Previous date from 1 April is 31th March and as month it's: 3   so what's the problem? please update Your question, make it clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If `Date` is today (2016-04-18), what should your query return as *previous April date*? If `Date` is 2016-01-01, what should it return? What about 2016-06-01? When posting a question here, please remember we can't read your mind to figure out what it is you're wanting to do, and we have no information other than what you include in your question.

Comment: I think he wants the most recent April 1 that precedes the date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

```
SELECT date,
CONCAT(IF(MONTH(date) < 4, YEAR(date) - 1, YEAR(date)), '-04-01') as month
FROM sometable
```